# Accessing service within directive - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to create a directive for async custom validation for model driven form.
Directive

```
    export default class AsyncValidator implements Validator {

    constructor(private fetchService: FetchService) { }

    validate(c: AbstractControl) {

        return this.validateUniqueNameObservable(c.value);
    }

    validateUniqueNameObservable(name: string) {

        return this.fetchService.fetchName(name).subscribe(observer => {
            if (name === observer) {
                observer.next({
                    asyncInvalid: true
                });
            } else {
                observer.next(null);
            }
        })
    }
   }
```

when the validation runs there is an exception "EXCEPTION: _this.subscribe is not a function". Can someone please point out what am i doing wrong with observable and subscription?
**Edit** - **Service**

```
public fetchName(name:string) {
    var result = this.http.get('/api/project/checkName/' +name).map(response => response.json());
    return result;
}
```

**Component**

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
public project: Project;
public createForm: FormGroup;//md form

constructor(private http:Http, private fb:FormBuilder) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.createForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.maxLength(150)]],
        client: ['', [<any>Validators.maxLength(150)]],
        notes: ['', [<any>Validators.maxLength(255)]]
    });
}
```

I am trying to create async custom validation for name form control, where it will call the fetchservice to check whether a name exists in the db and return an observable.

Comment: You are doing quite a few things wrong just a a glance. The specific error is complaining that your `fetchName` method from the injected service is not returning an `Observable` and therefore does not have a subscribe method. You should include the service code and actually explain what you are trying to do, since there are several mistakes here based on that you "think" happens.

Comment: fetchName method from service should return `Observable`.
can you please update your question and put service code here?

Comment: @smons you can check my answer below.